# Python USSD via com port

Tags: python

I am new to python. Is there anyway i can use python to send ussd with a phone via at+cusd commands. i can do that using hyperterminal. i want to automate using python. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/).

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial(0)  # open first serial port
>>> print ser.portstr       # check which port was really used
>>> ser.write("hello")      # write a string
>>> ser.close()             # close port
```